# On what confirmation leavel block metadata are produced

Tags: geyser

In geyser plugin there is [`notify_block_metadata()`](https://docs.rs/solana-geyser-plugin-interface/1.14.5/solana_geyser_plugin_interface/geyser_plugin_interface/trait.GeyserPlugin.html#method.notify_block_metadata) and I am curious if this block_metadata is produced always when slot is already rooted or can be produced also for `confirmed` and `processed` slots.

Answer (score 3):

In [Solana Official documented](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment) it says:

> "finalized" - the node will query the most recent block confirmed by supermajority of the cluster as having reached maximum lockout, meaning the cluster has recognized this block as finalized

> "confirmed" - the node will query the most recent block that has been voted on by supermajority of the cluster.
> It incorporates votes from gossip and replay.
> It does not count votes on descendants of a block, only direct votes on that block.
> This confirmation level also upholds "optimistic confirmation" guarantees in release 1.3 and onwards.

> "processed" - the node will query its most recent block. Note that the block may still be skipped by the cluster.

I personally use "processed" in dev mode as it only takes one confirmation (fastest confirmation mode), and before pushing it to mainnet, I set it to "finalized" to confirm that cluster has recognized this block. "finalized" will make you wait longer for confirmation.